# Symfony2 ACL combined with another criteria

Tags: symfony, acl

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an elegant way to achieve this using the Symfony2 ACL system.

I have a `Comment` entity (my domain object) which needs to be editable by `ROLE_USER` but this is only allowed within 5 minutes of the comment being posted - otherwise the comment can only be edited by `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Making it so that it can only be edited by `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN` is simple, just make a `RoleSecurityIdentity` for each.

Now my problem occurs when I want to incorporate the time factor for `ROLE_USER`. My first problem is that it needs information from the domain object, not just the ACL table but I think this is solvable by making a custom `ObjectIdentity` class which can also hold the time that the `Comment` was posted.

**Now for the hard part**

I think I need to create a custom `PermissionGrantingStrategy` that knows to also look at the creation time. This has to be loaded when a `Comment` type is being checked, but I don't know how to get it to load. Does anyone know if there's some kind of factory through which this sort of thing can be configured? So that if an entity has a specific `PermissionGrantingStrategy` associated with it then it gets used otherwise the default is used?

I know this is a bit of a long one, many thanks if anyone knows how to achieve this as the ACL documentation seems a tad sparse at the moment. My fallback solution is to simply make some kind of service to check if a Comment can be edited and not bother with ACL at all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you considered using a voter? There's a [cookbook recipe](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/voters.html) for implementing an IP blacklist voter, but it could be easily modified to handle checking for edits on Comment objects.

You can look at the default AclVoter at `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Voter\AclVoter` (online [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Voter/AclVoter.html)), though yours can obviously augment instead of replace it and be much simpler.

As a quick proof of concept:

```
class CommentTimestampVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {
        return 'edit' === $attribute;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        // 1. check if $token->getUser() has ROLE_ADMIN and return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED if so
        // 2. check if $token->getUser() equals $object->getAuthor() and return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED if not
        // 3. check that $object->getCreatedAt() is within the window allowed for editing and return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED if so
        // 4. return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return 'Acme\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment' === $class;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like what I need, plugs in nicely and also accessible through the security context's isGranted (which can also be used on my front end for conditionally showing controls to edit the comment). I'll give it a shot tonight and tick off the answer if it works but it looks like you're onto a winner :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok after implementing this solution I'd say it is the way to go but I'll post my code below incase it helps anyone out as I found alot of pitfalls when creating a voter, so hopefully my code might serve as documentation (although I can't guarantee correctness) to others.

Answer (score 35):

I'm posting this solution so that others can see my final code but here are the pitfalls I found when implementing a Voter as Problematic suggested.

**supportsAttribute**: It appears that when you call the `isGranted` method on the `SecurityContext` that it doesn't actually check this method before delegating a `vote` call to a `VoterInterface` so inside your `vote` method you actually have to check the attributes yourself.

**supportsClass**: In problematic's answer above it seemed like this method could be a key for a Factory based selection of which `VoterInterface`s can vote but actually the symfony2 documentation reads:

> The supportsClass() method is used to check if the voter supports the current user token class.

Therefore it actually seems to pertain to whether or not the `Voter` supports the token type. To make matters worse the PHP Doc seems vague:

> Checks if the voter supports the given class.

At any rate the main problem is that this method is never checked by the `SecurityContext` before delegating the call to the `vote` method of any voter - ***even if this method is hardcoded to `return false` `vote` will still be called!***

So basically the moral of the story appeared to be: check the `$attributes` and `$object` coming in on the `vote` method manually.

***My Code:***

services.yml

```
parameters:
    comment_voter.class: Acme\Bundle\CommentBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\CommentVoter

services:
    comment_voter:
        class: %comment_voter.class%
        arguments:  [@service_container]
        public: false
        tags:
          - { name: security.voter }
```

and the voter class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\CommentBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

use Acme\Bundle\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * A class to check editing privileges for Comments.
 */
class CommentVoter implements VoterInterface {

    const AUTHOR_EDIT_TIME_LIMIT    = 300;

    private $container;

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function supportsAttribute($attribute) {
        return $attribute === 'EDIT';
    }

    public function supportsClass($class) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether or not the current user can edit a comment.
     * 
     * Users with the role ROLE_COMMENT_MODERATOR may always edit.
     * A comment's author can only edit within 5 minutes of it being posted.
     * 
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes) {
        if ( !($object instanceof Comment) ) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        // Only supports 'EDIT' for now.
        if ( !$this->supportsAttribute($attributes[0]) ) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();
        if ( !($user instanceof UserInterface) ) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

        // Is the token a comment moderator?
        if ( $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_COMMENT_MODERATOR') ) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }

        // Is the token the author of the post and within the edit window.
        $originalRevision = $object->getOriginalRevision();
        if ( $originalRevision->getAuthor()->equals($user) ) {
            if ( 
                (time() - $originalRevision->getCreationDate()->getTimestamp())
                <= self::AUTHOR_EDIT_TIME_LIMIT
            ) {
                return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
        }

        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

}
```

and finally template:

```
{% if is_granted('EDIT', comment) %}<a href="#">Edit</a>{% endif %}
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future and a big thanks to Problematic for pointing me in the direction of Voters.

Comment: Thanks @Problematic and kasheen, This would be a great addition to Symfony cookbook https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs ;) You should submit a PR.