# Why to implement the supportsClass & supportsAttribute methods when implementing a voter?

Tags: security, symfony

As you can see in the following links, the supportsClass & supportsAttribute methods aren't called when we call isGranted():

- [pitfalls found when implementing a Voter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921844/539560)
- [AccessDecisionManager](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php)

Does these methods being called in other places?

Why they are part of interface?

Comment: I noticed that also. An explanation would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like it's a normal behavior since the voter have to check for the class.

Here is a the solution to check the class :

```
function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{   
    $user = $token->getUser();

    //sometime the object is a class or a instance of Request
    if($object instanceOf \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request ){
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;   
    }else{
        $class = $object->getType();
        if($class == 'Vendor\\MyBundle\\Entity\\MyEntity'){
           return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED; 
        }
    }

    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;   
}
```