# Put users certain restrictions

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a system that will restrict users in doing certain operations when limit is reached. For example, assuming we have a free and premium account lets say a free user can create just ten posts in the system (or ten records in a db) whereas a premium user has not that restriction.

What is a good strategy to implement this in symfony 2, I know about ACL but to my understanding they just control access to resources.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Think again about using ACL + grouping users. Just move user between `premium` and `regular` groups.

You can use ACL not only to control resources, but control flow inside actions etc.

Take a look at example for answer that have 12 votes here: [Symfony2 ACL combined with another criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879173/symfony2-acl-combined-with-another-criteria)